# How can inspect an element added/remove when mouse enter/leave a link FireBug?

Tags: html, css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, firebug

I've Bootstrap tooltip plugin that is showing/hiding a `<div>` inside `<body>` when mouse is enter/leave an `<a>` element.

I can see the new `<div>` added to body when i use the element selector and pass over the link. But when i move the mouse again for inspect the new `<div>` style, of course the `<div>` is removed from DOM.

How can i select it to inspect the computed style? I need this because my tooltips show a bit different style from Bootstrap reference tooltips.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firebug 1.10 added a keyboard shortcut for "Break on.." (<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>). This is extremely handy in situations just like this (because normally you would have to move your mouse to Firebug, which will hide your popup).

- Open Firebug, go to "Script" panel.
- do your stuff on the page to show the tooltip
- click the keyboard shortcut to activate "Break on next".
- move the mouse away from the tooltip

Before any JS on the page is executed (e.g. the JS which hides the popup), Firebug will pause and you'll be free to inspect everything.

Answer (score 6):

There is a little trick I use : if you right click on the link while the tooltip is shown, then go directly to the firebug panel, the tooltip won't go away.

Or you could just set the trigger option to manual and showing it yourself : `$('#sel').tooltip('show')`.